# Missing Index detection SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, optimization, indexing

I'm am trying to learn how to detect a missing Indexes in `SQL Server 2014 Express` (this is a self study project).  I am using `AdventureWorks 2012` and an online tutorial.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
SELECT
    FirstName,
    MiddleName,
    LastName
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName = 'Harrson'
AND FirstName = 'Jesse';
```

The query returns an empty table, which I am okay with (again I'm try to learn how to use the optimizer).

The tutorial indicates that I should right click the operation and a fly will appear with the missing Index option.  When I right click the only menu I see is the one below.

[Execution Plan Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYTQT.png)

Comment: There isn't a missing index, it's using a clustered index that is in place already.  If you were to drop that index then it might start telling you that it would be a good idea to create one.

Comment: can you please paste the schema of table and indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing index details do not always appear (it will be green text).  For your query, the clustered index is just fine and SQL Server sees no issue with it. You can try two other things:

- make your query more complex and add some joins and filters in the where clause. This may produce a index recommendation.
- Script out the current indexes on the table, save the scripts, then delete all indexes on the person.person table, and finally rerun your query. Chances are this will generate an index recommendation for the heap.  Once you are done playing around, you can rerun your index scripts to put the indexes back.